# Swift & SwiftUI - Conditional global var

Tags: swift, swiftui

I want to make a global variable in Swift, so that its `Data` is accessible to any view that needs it.  Eventually it will be a `var` so that I can mutate it, but while trying to get past this hurdle I'm just using it as `let`

I can do that by putting this as the top of a file (seemingly any file, Swift is weird):

```
let myData: [MyStruct] = load("myDataFile.json)
```

`load()` returns a `JSONDecoder()`. `MyStruct` is a `:Hashable, Codable, Identifiable` `struct`

That data is then available to any view that wants it, which is great. However, I want to be able to specify the file that is loaded based on a condition - I'm open to suggestions, but I've been using an `@AppStorage` variable to determine things when inside a `View`.

What I'd like to do, but can't, is do something like:

```
@AppStorage("appStorageVar") var appStorageVar: String = "Condition1"
if(appStorageVar == "Condition2") {
    let myData: [MyStruct] = load("myDataFile2.json")
}
else {
    let myData: [MyStruct] = load("myDataFile.json")
}
```

I can do this inside a `View`'s `body`, but then it's only accessible to that `View` and then I have to repeat it constantly, which can't possibly the correct way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change just change the global in an `onChange` on the AppStorage variable. This is an answer to your question, but you have the problem that no view is going to be updating itself when the global changes.

```
var myData: [MyStruct] = load("myDataFile.json)

struct ContentView: View {
    @AppStorage("appStorageVar") var appStorageVar: String = "Condition1"
    var body: some View {
        Button("Change value") {
           appStorageVar = "Condition2"
        }
        .onChange(of: appStorageVar) { newValue in
            myData = load(newValue == "Condition1" ? "myDataFile.json" : "myDataFile2.json")  
        }
    }
}
```